# Call closure function from Dev Tools

Tags: javascript

Say there is a bundled file `app.d2n72bla.js` in the source of a website. The file contains a bunch of functions :

```
function closeCookiePreferencePopup(){
    var e;
    this.closeCookiePopup(),
    null === (e = this.resolver) || void 0 === e || e.call(this)
}

function openCookiePreferencePopup(){
        var e;
        this.openCookiePopup(),
        null === (e = this.resolver) || void 0 === e || e.call(this)
}
....
```

How can I trigger `openCookiePreferencePopup()` from the Chrome Dev tools?

Edit: This is how the script tag is added:

```
x = function(e) {
   return new Promise(((t,n)=>{
   const r = a.createElement("script");
   r.src = e,
   r.async = !0,
   r.addEventListener("error", (e=>{
     n(e)
    })),
   r.addEventListener("load", (e=>{
     t(e)
    })),
   a.head.append(r)
   }))
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Well, that code is invalid - a function requires `()` (at the very least) after the name.

Comment: @Andy Correct, have just edited - sorry for that !

Comment: What is the context? Why can't you just call the function?

Comment: So did  you try? What happened?

Comment: @epascarello Got the following error : Uncaught ReferenceError: openCookiePreferencePopup is not defined

Comment: So the function is not in global scope it appears. Hard for us to guess a solution for you.

Comment: @Andy I need to be able fully interact with a site from the dev tools

Comment: @epascarello Yes, it's not , but does that automatically imply it cannot be called , even if the script is served ?

Comment: It is IMPOSSIBLE for us to guess since we have ZERO information about the code. We have a small window into the black box, we can not see anything else.

Comment: It only implies it's not exposed in the global scope. Whether it can or cannot be called from other parts of the code will depend on whether a) they try to call it from global scope (we don't know that) b) they have access to the function within their scope (we also don't know that)

Comment: @epascarello Alright, thanks a lot ! But if you had more details - are there any steps you would take in order to assess this ?

Comment: Show how the script tag is added, is it a module? Can you not share more code?

Comment: @epascarello Have just edited the question to reflect that, hope it's useful!

Comment: So it is not a module so it comes down to how it is written that prevents the methods from being global.

Comment: @epascarello Yes! Is it reasonable to assume in this case that under no circumstance can I trigger these functions in the console? Or are there any possibilities?

Comment: Impossible to know with what you provided.